# Use geometry data type in dynamic query

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am creating a function in PostgreSQL with PostGIS where I accept tables name and the geometry of point and I want to use them in a query inside the function......

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trial(tbl text[],tag text[],geo geometry)
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE i integer;
DECLARE len integer;
DECLARE result boolean;
DECLARE bool boolean;

BEGIN
    result=true;
    SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(tbl,1) INTO len;
    FOR i IN 1..len LOOP
    EXECUTE format('select st_dwithin(geo::geography,geom::geography,1) from %s where name=any(array[%s]) and st_dwithin(geo::geography,geom::geography,1)=true',tbl[i],tag[i]) into bool;

        IF (bool!=true) THEN
        result=false;
        EXIT;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    return result;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

this shows me the error as

```
LINE 1: select st_dwithin(geo::geography,geom::geography,1) from grn...
```

when I use

> %s for that geometry

I get the next error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AA40E9A0E5440F498329474092A40"
LINE 1: select st_dwithin(0101000020E6100000002AA40E9A0E5440F4983294...
```

I am a beginner in PostgreSQL... What format specifier can I use in this case?????

Comment: why not save the format result in a string to debug that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with your function.

First of all, in the `format()` function you can only splice in identifiers and literal values while you need to pass a `geography` and a `text[]`, both parameters of your function. This basically means that you cannot use the `format()` function but you should instead [use the `USING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). This, incidentally, is good news because `format()` produces a string and that is quite inefficient (you pass in a `geometry` which gets converted to a string by `format()` and then parsed back into a `geometry` in the server, once for each iteration of the loop). The `geo` parameter, being a PL/pgSQL variable, will not be resolved by `EXECUTE` so it must also be supplied through the `USING` clause.

The dynamic query itself is not particularly well written either. The logic says that you want to return `true` if at least 1 row having one of the `tags` is located within 1 meter from `geo`. Efficiently written, that query would be:

```
SELECT 1 FROM <table>
WHERE name = ANY(<tags>)
  AND ST_DWithin(<geo>, geom::geography, 1, false)
LIMIT 1;
```

This obviously assumes that all tables have a `name` and `geom` column. If `geom` is of `geography` type you can omit the cast. Use `false` for calculations on the sphere, which is more than adequate for this short distance  and much faster to calculate.

Together with some flow logic improvements, your function then becomes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trial(tbl text[], tag text[], geo geography)
RETURNS boolean AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  t   text;
  res int;
BEGIN
  FOREACH t IN ARRAY tbl LOOP 
    EXECUTE 'SELECT 1 FROM ' || quote_ident(t) ||
            '  WHERE name = ANY($1)' ||
            '    AND ST_DWithin($2, geom::geography, 1, false) ' ||
            'LIMIT 1'
        INTO res USING tags, geo;

    IF res IS NULL THEN     -- No value was returned so no nearby points
      RETURN false;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN true;              -- If we get here, all tables have at least 1 match
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function takes an array of table names and then determines if all tables have at least 1 point with any of the supplied tags within 1 meter of a specified point. That does not sound too useful to me. Returning a set of `text` with each row giving the name of the table that does (or does not) meet that criterion looks far more useful, or perhaps even a `RETURNS TABLE (tbl name, num int, tags text[])` version that gives for each table the number of points within 1 meter and the matching tags for that table.

Comment: ur suggestion were very much useful to solve my prob.can u tell why we use `select 1 from table`

Comment: What you are testing for is the presence of some data, not the data itself. So you return just the simplest piece of data possible to signal that data is there: 1. If the data is not there, the `EXECUTE` statement will put `NULL` as a result, hence the change in the `IF ... THEN` test.